# Responsive site shows large right side margin on smart phones

Tags: android, iphone, css, responsive-design

We have programmed a site at: http://tcsdesignreno.com/zing-cards/ to be responsive. Whenever I check it in online responsive design test sites (such as: http://mattkersley.com/responsive/ or http://beta.screenqueri.es/) it looks fine but if I bring it up on a HTC Sensation, iPhone 5 or a Galaxy 3 it cuts off the right side of the screen. I have used the standard web browsers, safari, and chrome on each of the phones. I have tried to debug it by contecting my andriod phone to my pc but can't seem to find the issue.

There are no hard coded margins or anything else that I can find that would cause the phones to do this.

Thanks in advance for you help!

Matt

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to fix is the width on class="logos". For a responsive design, your breakpoints and widths should ideally be set in ems. You can remove the width declaration on that element and let it be fluid.

Another thing to look at is the negative margins that you've got on the Zing and Cards images.

Answer (score 0):

You can just resize your web browser to a small size and see the scroll bars that appear instead of using responsive test websites.

You have `padding: 0 20px;` on `<head>` that is contributing to the scroll bars. I'd peruse your CSS for padding/margins that could be contributing to this (like jbenjohnson said checkout your negative margins).

Comment: I have checked any negative margins and I fixed the large margin (Thanks!) on screens smaller than 500px but I still have a smaller (10 - 20px) margin problem on the right side of my ipad and cell phones. I can't seem to find the code that is causing it. Any other ideas would be appreciated.